# Implement HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on VisualSVN

Tags: visualsvn-server, hsts

Our cycber security have recommended the introduction of HTTP Strict-Transport-Security response headers, but cannot see anywhere in VisualSVN (or the configuration of it) to do this.

This is for **VisualSVN Enterprise 4.2.2** (using **Apache 1.10.6**) running on **Windows 2019 DataCenter**.

I see no separate installation of Apache, no presence of a httpd.exe on the server and there's a header warning in the httpd.conf file which advises tha the conf will be overwritten when/if the VisualSVN service is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line to the %VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd-custom.conf file and restart the VisualSVN Server service:

`Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"`

Note that you may need to replace the max-age value with another one depending on your requirements.